# Linking ASIO to a project without boost in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-asio

I'm trying to use asio without boost for a project in visual studio.

I've added the headers by adding `asio\include` to the `Additional Include Directories` in my project's properties.  This allows my project to see the headers, and intellisense properly finds all of the objects.  So far, so good.

However, when I try to compile, I get errors that I can't find boost headers such as:

`cannot open source file "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp"  example-udpreceiver c:\Users\me\project\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio\deadline_timer.hpp`

or

`cannot open source file "boost/regex/v4/match_flags.hpp"   example-udpreceiver c:\Users\me\project\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio\detail\regex_fwd.hpp`

My impression is that it was possible to use asio without boost -- what do I need to do to get asio compiling with my project?

thanks!

Comment: Did you download asio from here? http://think-async.com/

Comment: I did download it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `ASIO_STANDALONE` macro to get asio working properly in standalone mode.

Comment: Should it be set to anything in particular, or is just `#define ASIO_STANDALONE` enough?

Comment: I recommend to add the definition to the `Configuration Properties` > `C/C++` > `Preprocessor ` > `Preprocessor Defintions` (or CMake's `add_definitions`). Otherwise you would need to take care about to define the macro before every asio inclusion. Probably it's enough to just set the macro.

Comment: Thanks; that worked for resolving boost dependencies!  There's still an odd error of type `D8049 -- cannot execute c1xx.dll: command line is too long to fit in debug record`, but it's not clear if this is related to the inclusion of asio or not (yet).

Comment: I tested the standalone version in a small example which worked : http://pastebin.com/LfQvg8pB . I doubt that your error is related to asio in any way.

Comment: Hmm, so when I try to actually add this to a project, I get the error: `error C2039: 'CreateEvent': is not a member of 'global namespace''`.  Any ideas what's causing that?  `ASIO_STANDALONE` and `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` are both defined in the preprocessor.